# Old VHS horror movie where boy and mother and hunted by monster

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I'm looking for the title of an old VHS horror movie. 
From what I can recall, the movie could possibly have been made between 1998 and 2004

The setting of the movie was a kid and his mother in a rural, rocky mountain/woods kind of location.

The film starts with the mum talking to the teacher about the boy being nasty, but the teacher is horrible herself.

Then, something happens where, during the whole movie, the mum and son run away from this creature as it hunts them through this town.

There is a scene in which they take refuge in a bar, and the son goes to the bathroom, and he is in the stall, and the monster is in there with them. He escapes with this mum whilst the people inside are killed or try to fight it off.

In another scene, the monster is at their home, and the teacher from the start, for some reason, is there and ends up coming in contact with the monster and she ends up being killed by being dragged under the house.

That is everything I can recall from the movie. If anyone has an idea of what this movie could be, or what it is, I would be truly grateful.

The movie was an American made movie with a movie it was in English.

I can't remember what the monster looked like but it could have been something that came from a cave or some sort of curse or demon that was chasing him.

That's everything I can remember of this movie unfortunately

Comment: Only plot details I remember is what I wrote already which is annoying I know. The rest I can remember was it was when VHS was still around and being used regularly it isn't an old movie like I said its at least 1998 to 2004 possibly 2005 movie? 

Also, I remember the bar scene ended with the bar staff like an old man telling the women and child to run, as himself and others were shooting at the creature and as they ran out the bar they heard them being killed and shooting at the creature.

Comment: I *think* there was a similar question before and the answer was [The Day the World Ended](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0272575/combined) from 2001, but unfortunately, I can't find the original question nor remember much of the film. See if [this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLqaZyD2qRc) looks familiar.

Comment: Got it thank you! The movie was "The day the world ended" it's a cheesy film but it's something that scared me to death as a child

Answer (score 4):

This is [The Day the World Ended](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0272575/combined) from 2001 with Nastassja Kinski and    Randy Quaid.

> When a killer alien creature, who is misunderstood, begins killing specific members of a small town, a school psychologist learns of its link to a young boy's tragic childhood, and his adoptive father's dark secret.

IIRC it takes place in the environment you mentioned and that monster follows the kid around, killing everyone being nasty to him (including some bullies, I think, and a nasty teacher that gets dragged under a house). But I'm pretty sure the female lead that tries to help him (played by Kinski) is a psychologist, not his mom. Here's the trailer: